GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration() changed from Java 8 to Java 17
I have the following code:
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;


public class GraphicsEnvironmentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                
        GraphicsEnvironment localGraphicsEnvironment = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice defaultScreenDevice = localGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        GraphicsConfiguration defaultConfiguration = defaultScreenDevice.getDefaultConfiguration();
        
        System.out.println("defaultConfiguration.getBounds() " + defaultConfiguration.getBounds());
        System.out.println("defaultConfiguration.getDefaultTransform() " + defaultConfiguration.getDefaultTransform());

    }

}


With Java 8 i get the following:
defaultConfiguration.getBounds() java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=2560,height=1600]
defaultConfiguration.getDefaultTransform() AffineTransform[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]

With Java 17 i get the following:
defaultConfiguration.getBounds() java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1707,height=1067]
defaultConfiguration.getDefaultTransform() AffineTransform[[1.5, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.5, 0.0]]

Why is this different? Is this a bug?
Here the exact java versions:
Java 8: 1.8.0_242
Java 17: Eclipse Adoptium - Temurin-17.0.7+7

You can only reproduce this, if you have a scaling different from 100% of your operating system. Go to system->screen setting.


Do you have several screens?

I've tried reproducing your problem without success. I get the expected result (java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1920,height=1080] and AffineTransform[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]) for both calls with Java 8, Java 17 and Java 22.
Which JDK are you using? What's your setup? How are you compiling and running the program? You're probably overlooking some important information

Those values transform to same. Edit with more details of which JDK and OS. If Windows check default font scaling.

Do you have several screens? -> no only one screen

You can only reproduce this, if you have a a scaling screen setting of operating system. I attached this step to reproduce in text.

I found a JVM parameter, which disable scaling. This fixes the problem:
-Dsun.java2d.uiScale.enabled=false

See also:
How to disable scaling the UI on Windows, for Java 9 applications?

I can reproduce the change you noticed if my screen display scaling is not 100%. At this point, the coordinates and scaling reported by JDK8 and JDK23 differ. As I have two screens, I use this test program:
GraphicsDevice[] screens = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices();
Arrays.stream(screens).map(GraphicsDevice::getDefaultConfiguration).forEach(device -> {
    System.out.println("getBounds() " + device.getBounds());
    System.out.println("getDefaultTransform() " + device.getDefaultTransform());
});

At 100% I see identity AffineTransform on both JDK:
getBounds() java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1920,height=1080]
getDefaultTransform() AffineTransform[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
getBounds() java.awt.Rectangle[x=-1680,y=32,width=1680,height=1050]
getDefaultTransform() AffineTransform[[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]

At 110% the bounds and AffineTransform changed on newer JDK (1920 being ~ 1739 x 1.104166626930237):
getBounds() java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1739,height=978]
getDefaultTransform() AffineTransform[[1.104166626930237, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.104166626930237, 0.0]]
getBounds() java.awt.Rectangle[x=-1680,y=32,width=1522,height=951]
getDefaultTransform() AffineTransform[[1.104166626930237, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.104166626930237, 0.0]]

Most likely, the reason for this difference will be explained by searching the JDK bug database and checking release version JDK9+. Two worth noting in particular:

Window positioning bugs due to overlapping GraphicsDevice bounds (Windows/HiDPI) Fixed JDK16
Bounds of GraphicsConfiguration are incorrect on scaled HDPI monitors in JDK16 Not an Issue

Reverting to 100% scale will ensure the JDKs report same values. If this applies to your case, it is JDK8 that is incorrect, and JDK17 is correct.
Note that you can access the scaled and unscaled getBounds in later JDKs by reading DisplayMode, so it might be possible to write same code for JDK8 and later JDKs if you can only depend on the "unscaled" version of the screen bounds rather than the scaled getBounds() values:
Arrays.stream(screens).map(GraphicsDevice::getDefaultConfiguration)
      .forEach(conf -> {
        DisplayMode dm = conf.getDevice().getDisplayMode();
        Rectangle bounds = conf.getBounds();
        System.out.println(conf+".getBounds() " + bounds);
        System.out.println(conf+" unscaled    " + new Rectangle((int)bounds.getX(), (int)bounds.getY(), dm.getWidth(), dm.getHeight()));
    });
// JDK23 output for "unscaled" matches JDK8:
getBounds() java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1739,height=978]
unscaled    java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1920,height=1080]
getBounds() java.awt.Rectangle[x=-1680,y=32,width=1522,height=951]
unscaled    java.awt.Rectangle[x=-1680,y=32,width=1680,height=1050]


Thanks for your analysis. In my case screens has only 1 member. With Java 8 unscaled and scaled rectangle are the same and with Java 17 they are different, like you described.

Here is the resultig problem of this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78953638/scaled-volatileimage-with-bad-quality-with-java-17
